# 'ERR: QApplication before a QWidget' happened while use QWidget as Class member

Tags: python, qwidget, pyside6

When I try to define two QWidget var as class members, an error information is reported as the following,

"QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget"

To define QWidget obj as class members is for the reason that these two 'QWidget' obj need share data with each other, if I use the way like 'self.compUI1', they can not be accessed in class member functions.

Here is something (similar) what I planned to do,
`

```
class TabUISheet(QTabWidget):
   
    #define UI component as member

    compUI1 = PicUI()
    compUI2 = TxtUI()
    
    def
    
    ...
    
    def fun1():
        #here I need to get txt data
    
    def fun2():
        #here I need to update txt data to compUI1 (QWiget based)
```

`

Does that mean QWidgets can not be defined as class member?
Actually, 'TabUISheet' is called after calling 'QApplication()'

`

```
def main():


    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ...
    TabUISheet()
```

`

I have tried use self.compUI1, but failed because as I mentioned before this can be accessed by 'instance' rather than 'Class' or class member.

Not sure, if there is other way to realize that to share data between two QWidget based UI components.

Comment: It makes little sense to share widgets as class members, especially if you do it for sharing data (which is normally not widget-based). Can you please explain why are you doing this exactly, what kind of data needs to be shared and how?

Comment: Actually, I need to deal a UI with different sheets (widget based), some of the widget get input data from txt editor, and others need to read those data and display.